# Permissions issue in SSMS: "The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'extended_properties', database 'mssqlsystem_resource', ... Error 229)"

Tags: sql-server, security, t-sql, permissions, ssms

Here’s the simplest repro case possible.

1. Create a brand new database. (I'm using SQL 2005.)
2. Create a login, a SQL user, and a table in the new database (see sample code below).
3. Launch SSMS and open Object Explorer, logging in **as the newly-created user**.
4. Attempt to open the "Tables" folder in the Object Explorer.

### The Problem

Fails with **[this error message](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_KzXtwuR1Gmk/S0Ji8SjKSMI/AAAAAAAAC7k/o74ccJKTLpI/s1600-h/SSMS_Error.PNG)**.

**Message Text:**

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
> Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
> For help, click: [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476)
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'extended_properties', database mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)
> For help, click: [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.3282&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=229&LinkId=20476)

This user *can* access the table and the record in the table. But the user *cannot* access the list of tables in Object Explorer.

```
SELECT USER_NAME() AS CurrentUser, col1
FROM dbo.TestTable

CurrentUser col1
----------- ----
robg_test   1000
```

The only work-around I have found is to give the user higher-than-necessary privileges (like db_datareader).

### The Question:

What is the *minimum* privilege required to allow this user to open the table list in Object Explorer?

I have tried granting the user various privileges on the dbo schema, but that did not help.

Note also that I am using a SQL user simply to illustrate the problem. The original problem was with an AD user.

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/43606/what-permissions-might-be-missing-on-error-229-from-tables-node-on-ssms-object) is a relatively similar question at serverfault.

---

### Code

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
USE master
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'robg_test')
    DROP LOGIN [robg_test]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [robg_test]
WITH
    PASSWORD         = N'CLK63!!black',
    DEFAULT_DATABASE = [RGTest],
    DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [us_english],
    CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF,
    CHECK_POLICY     = ON
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'RGTest')
    DROP DATABASE [RGTest]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [RGTest]
GO
USE [RGTest]
GO
CREATE USER [robg_test] FOR LOGIN [robg_test] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo]
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable (col1 int)
GO
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.TestTable TO [robg_test]
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable VALUES (1000)
GO
```

Comment: As I stated below, I retried this on SQL Server 2008 and had the same problem. I am using SSMS 2008 to connect to both instances.

Comment: Here is another somewhat-related link: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;956179. However, this has to do with opening the "Databases" folder.

Comment: Based on a suggestion here (http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=376819), I started a trace and found the exact command causing the error. Inside that larger command was the actual piece that causes the error: "select major_id from sys.extended_properties". See the complete command here: http://robsonlinereference.blogspot.com/2010/01/permissions-issue-in-ssms.html. That is not the only piece that would cause a permissions error, but it is the one that is causing this specific permissions error.

Comment: May I ask you to verify if Eltigani's answer below solves the issue for you as well and if yes accept this answer?

Comment: It got resolved for my by just logging via adminstrator login.  Eg. right click SSMS icon -> Click Run as administrator --> In object navigator once you login (say windows login) attach a Database (eg. Adventure works 2022), it gets attached successfully. If you normal login without Admin the below is seeen. Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Please check that you didn't check `db_denydatareader` DB role. By removing that check it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks... I check deny_reader instead of reader... go figure.

Comment: That's incredible I thought granting permission means checking all the items!!

Comment: Now I understand why "Less is More" !

Answer (score 10):

I had similar problem and resolved that by removing two roles db_denydatareader and db_denydatawriter for that user and add other roles. I used sql management studio.

Answer (score 1):

SSMS tries to get the extended properties of the table using [`fn_listextendedproperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179853.aspx). According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx) the required permisions to view a table's extended properties is

> ALTER on table OBJECT

Your login test should have this permsision as owner of the test table (it is the owner, right?). But even if you don't have permissions on the table, the query for extended properties should return emtpy result set, not access denied. The fact that you get an access denied error on a sys object in the resource database indicates that the code signing of the system resource database (mssqlsystemresource) is broken. Did you drop any of the '##' certificates from master? did you manually altered any object in the resource database?

Anyway, you have a what looks like a corrupted instance at this moment and I'd recommend you contact product support on how to get it back into a coherent state.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think that's the problem. I just retried the whole process on a different instance and server, this time using SQL Server 2008. I got the exact same error. (I am using SSMS 2008 to connect to both instances.)

Comment: Also understand that I am trying to open the "Tables" folder, not the extended properties of a particular table.

Comment: Regarding "Your login test should have this permission as owner of the test table (it is the owner, right?).": the test SQL login is not the owner of the table. The database, login, and table were all created by a login with significantly higher privileges.

Comment: Answers to specific questions in the reply: I have not dropped any of the '##' certificates from master in either of these instances. I have not manually altered any object in the resource database.

Comment: Viewing extended properties is not granted by SELECT permission. Though SSMS should not just Throw an error in you face like that. I need to look at a Server when I get my hands on one, right now I'm just taping on my phone...

Comment: Thanks Remus. See my comment on the question about the trace. It shows exactly what the query is that causes the error.

Comment: Resolution:

Remus Rusanu was on the right track. I had been working through removing all the public permissions from our application databases. As part of that analysis, I revoked a whole list of public permissions on 119 "[sys]." objects (e.g., [sys].[sysprotects], [sys].[schemas]).

I connected to an untouched SQL 2005 instance and reran this whole test. That time, there was no error. I have not narrowed it down to the exact permission that made it fail, but re-granting that set of permissions to public made the problem go away. Still not happy with the public permissions, but it's working.

Comment: Also see a related entry at connect.microsoft.com: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=520750

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I resolved it by adding the user to the public role.  But if you didn't want to do that, I also found that it could be resolved by giving the user permission to the view sys.extended-properties (in System Views within the database that you're trying to access)

Answer (score 0):

"By creating the SQL server db with an account, that account is owner and has all needed access"

No need for further enhancements in permissions.

This approach removed the access error which this thread seems about. 
I encountered the access error in SSMS, as well as Visual Studio (EF), using windows authentication and having created the SQL server DB with the Administrator account.

Practical solution for me was :

SSMS > start as administrator, sql server logon : with windows authentication
- NOT to create an SQL server db
- but to give an account 'create db any' permission on 'master'

then SSMS logon with that account (that has 'create db any' permissions on master)
- to create the (empty) database

(VISUAL STUDIO xtra :
then, in visual studio, connect to sql server with that account and compare schema's between LocalDB (source) and sql server db (target). works out well : the target db gets the schema and data content)

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved for my by just logging via adminstrator login.  Eg. right click SSMS icon -> Click Run as administrator --> In object navigator once you login (say windows login) attach a Database (eg. Adventure works 2022), it gets attached successfully. If you normal login without Admin the below is seeen. Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc