# access error sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a user but when I try to view a database tables, I'm having the following error messages:

Please note that I am able to login but not having access to the database.

> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>
> ### (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'extended_properties',
>   database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema
>   'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)

Comment: Did you give any permissions to the created users?

Comment: yes, the user has been assigned the permissions

Answer (score 0):

Did you map the login to the user?

```
EXEC SP_Change_Users_Login 'Update_One','user','login',Null
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In the **Secutity -> Logins -> userName**, check the database is selected in the list or not.
2. In the **Database -> Security -> UserName** check the role member has sufficient priviliges.

[Check out this one](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/520750/do-not-grant-object-permissions-to-public-by-default)

[Another marked an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002773/permissions-issue-in-ssms-the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-exten)

[More Links](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/86e4a14e-0f42-4c2e-b1a3-a29221cc240c/)