# How to restore large Sql Database

Tags: sql-server, restore

I'm trying to restore a large Database from my local machine to server.
But i'm unable to restore it by `Sql Script` because i am unable to create the script it gives some error.

But when i'm going to restore by backup File. i.e .bak file . it does not allow me to restore it gives an error

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'extended_properties',
>   database 'mssqlsystem_resource', … Error 229).

And a part from this i have a doubt if i am database restore successfully then it will create a database instance but on server a database name instance already created.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us youre sql restore script - And your error is possible because you dont have enough permissions

Comment: Sorry but i am unable to create a sql script. it always failed when i am trying to create a script. I have only back up file.

Comment: have you any idea how can i give permission?

Comment: Right click your user under security and give it sysadmin or dbowner and make sure these are NOT checked db_denydatareader and db_denydatawriter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permissions issue in SSMS: "The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'extended\_properties', database 'mssqlsystem\_resource', ... Error 229)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002773/permissions-issue-in-ssms-the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-exte)

Comment: Yes it was duplicate and i'd comment there too but didn't got reply that's why i'd  to post my question. 
Thanks a lot for your time  :)